# RaiseEvent seems to not execute properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

New to photon networking I am using raise events for my board game. Sometimes event won't fire, but most of the time they work fine need help.

```
private void OnEnable() {
      
   PhotonNetwork.NetworkingClient.EventReceived += NetworkingClient_EventReceived;

 }

private void Disable()
    {
      
       PhotonNetwork.NetworkingClient.EventReceived -= NetworkingClient_EventReceived;
    }

 private void NetworkingClient_EventReceived(EventData obj)
    {
 
        byte eventCode = obj.Code;

        if (eventCode == (byte)EnumGame.DiceRoll)
        {

            EventManager.instance.rolldiceEvent(obj);
        }

        if (eventCode == (byte)EnumGame.DiceNumber)
        {

            EventManager.instance.displaydiceNumber(obj);
        }

        if (eventCode == (byte)EnumGame.Passdice)
        {

            EventManager.instance.passdicetootherPlayer(obj);


        }


        if (eventCode == (byte)EnumGame.PassTurn)
        {

            EventManager.instance.passturntootherPlayer(obj);
        

        }

    }
```

This is how I use to raise event in my script I am not getting any kind of exception:

```
    object[] data = new object[] { Photonplayer.instance.getplayerId() };
        RaiseEventOptions raiseEventOptions = new RaiseEventOptions { Receivers = ReceiverGroup.Others };
        PhotonNetwork.RaiseEvent((byte)EnumGame.Passdice, data, raiseEventOptions, SendOptions.SendUnreliable);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 object[] data = new object[] { Photonplayer.instance.getplayerId() };
    RaiseEventOptions raiseEventOptions = new RaiseEventOptions { Receivers = ReceiverGroup.Others };
    PhotonNetwork.RaiseEvent((byte)EnumGame.Passdice, data, raiseEventOptions, SendOptions.SendReliable);
```

Change "SendOptions.SendUnreliable" to "SendOptions.SendReliable" in RaiseEvent's 4th parameter.